# How can I calculate vapor pressure from temperature and relative humidity?

Tags: temperature, humidity

I have a datalogger that records temperature and relative humidity in a room.  Can I use that to calculate vapor pressure?

Comment: How would uncontained vapor pressure be different from atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Vapor pressure is a function of temperature only.  Google "Antoine Equation".

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is a psychrometric chart with p = RT/v, v = specific volume.  R = 0.286 kJ/kg/K and is NOT the familiar *universal* constant R = 8.31 J/mole/K.

[enter link description here](https://www.ghlinc.com/documents/T_chartes_equivalences/Chartes_chartepsychrometriquefarenheits.pdf)
Psychrometric chart for air

[enter link description here](http://www.ecaa.ntu.edu.tw/weifang/class-cea/Using%20a%20Psychrometric%20Chart%20to%20Describe%20Air%20Properties,%20AEX-120-99.htm)
Using a psychrometric chart